# Advanced Swift2 - Implementing Protocols in Class Vs Implementing Protocols in Struct

Tags: struct, protocols, swift2, ios9

// Protocol

```
Protocol Movable {
  mutating func moveTo(p : CGPoint) 
}
```

While Implementing a Protocol in a Class here is the Syntax

```
Class Car : Movable {
 func moveTo(p : CGPoint) {...} 
}
Struct Shape : Movable {
 mutating func moveTo(p : CGPoint) {...} 
}
```

Now why do have to insert "mutating" in struct , whats it doing underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because structs are by default assumed to be immutable, while class instances are assumed to be mutable. Therefore you don't need to mark a function that modifies a class instance, but you must mark a method that modifies a struct. Assume you wrote `let myShape = Shape()`. The compiler needs to know that it cannot let you call `myShape.moveTo(...)`.